# Including summary statistics in stargazer rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

I would like to change the default summary statistics displayed in stargazer for my glm() models. By default it displays number of obervations, log likelihood and the AIC.

Now, I'd like to add a Likelihood Ratio Test and the BIC.

The arguments `keep.stat` only controls the default statistics.

Is it even possible to add other statistics than the default ones?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best,
John

Comment: Likely no, except by hand with the argument `add.lines`. But hard to know with out more details (e.g. what kind of object are you send to stargazer?) and a minimal working example to test.